Microsoft Word deletes paragraphs from my manuscripts during OneCloud syncing. Is there a way to recover?
Background: I decided to write my manuscript for my novel in Microsoft Word, due to the quick start and apparent syncing possibilities (even from the smartphone). Now I write most of the time in libraries where they only have public WLAN, which I don't want to use, and actually don't need to as I just wanna add some paragraphs (and am fine with syncing it online later). So far, I've only written on my laptop and nowhere else.
Problem: While in the first days, it worked quite well just syncing later. In the past days, I got increasingly blocked. Microsoft Word refusing to open or close without an online connection or doing so with minutes of delay.
Now it has become even worse: Some paragraph I certainly added offline (with the expectation they would sync later) went missing. I'm not even sure if they weren't much more, as I tend to randomly edit and improve here and there.
I tried the online version history, and the last version was 5 days ago (I write every day without exception). However some of my edits from the last days actually appeared in today's document.
Goal: Is there a way, to recover not the online versions, but the changes made offline, before Microsoft mangled my manuscript?

You mention using smartphone: Are the "missing" sections edited/made on your mobile device? When you look at the file versions for the document, do you see the versions you are saying were offline?

@music2myear I never used my smartphone for editing the document so far. I just said I choose Word because I may want to do that in the future.

For any document you value, such as a novel into which you've put many hours work, make backup copies on a regular basis, and put them on external media. On occasion, material in the cloud is lost (e.g., https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/google/google-drive-users-angry-over-losing-months-of-stored-data/), or a µSD card, HDD or SSD goes bad.

Never work with flash drives directly from Word. Use Word with your document on your computer's local drive. If you want to save to an external source, do it from the operating system, not from Word. Do not open, edit, or print a document on an external drive from within Word. I would never use anything but one of the desktop applications for editing an important document. For future reference, see http://www.gmayor.com/automatically_backup.htm. That will give you more control.

Microsoft Word creates temporary backup copies of your document while you're working on it. These files are stored in the AutoRecover folder. To locate this folder, go to File > Options > Save in Word, and note the location listed under "AutoRecover file location." Then, navigate to that folder using File Explorer and look for any files that match the name of your manuscript.

There was indeed a LiveRecovery save, and a AutoRecovery save of my file to be found in the stated folder. Both however were totaling 0KB, and just opening completely empty documents.
